# How to use Counters in apache crunch

Tags: apache-crunch

In Apache Crunch , there is method named `increment("any enum")`.

I used `increment(TOTAL_IDS);`, but where I can see the result of counters, counters are not coming in logs after completion of job.

What am I missing there?

Comment: Reviewed syntax

Comment: Can you help me here, how to use counters in crunch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to see your counters in the tracking URL of the mapreduce job (if you are running mapreduce) or extract the counters from the pipeline. It would be useful if you could provide your code how you are incrementing the counters? is it in your DoFn, in your cleanp method?

Regards

Comment: Thanks Lake. I am able to see my counter in tracking url of the mapreduce job.